# Setting up Amplitude analytics, I get ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: amplitude-analytics

I'm trying to set up Amplitude for my web app.

When I click on a button that should be tracked, I get this:

`POST https://api2.amplitude.com/2/httpapi net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Answer (score 1):

Amplitude tracks user actions, so of course my ad block didn't like it.

I added amplitude.com , localhost and my domain to the allow-list of my ad-blocker and this started working well.